# Dependency Injection: Accessing a database based on URL parameter - how to do it properly

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a piece of working code that allows me to access a specific database based on a URL parameter. However, I am not fully satisfied with the way I implemented it and want to know how I can improve upon my code.

What I currently have is a DatabaseService which gets injected into a controller using DI. In this DatabaseService I have an Init() method which allows me to pass on the name of the database. The database name itself is retrieved by a controller base-class which overrides "OnActionExecuting" to retrieve the database name from the URL.

Controller-base:

```
public class LoadDatabaseControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected IDatabaseService Database;

    public LoadDatabaseControllerBase(IDatabaseService databaseService)
    {
        Database = databaseService;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

        var databaseName = Request.Host.Host.Split('.').First();

        Database.Init(databaseName);
    }
}
```

DatabaseService:

```
[...]

public DatabaseService(ILogger<DatabaseService> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public void Init(string databaseName)
{
    _repository = new LiteDbRepository(databaseName);
}

[...]
```

There are a couple of things I don't like about this:

1. You need to KNOW to call Init() on the database. If you forget, you will get a lot of errors without a clear indication of where they are coming from.
2. The repository called within the DatabaseService is not injectable since I need to pass it the database name. If I want to make it injectable I will again need to add an Init() or property that I have to set before using the repository, which in turn will result in the same issue as above

So, my question: How would you solve this issue?

- Would you create a transient settings class which you populate in the controller and inject into the DatabaseService and Repository?
- Is there a way to delay/pass the database name directly to DI so it can instantiate with the correct database name?
- Other ways?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `Would you create a transient settings class which you populate in the controller and inject into the DatabaseService and Repository?` How would you propose to make that work?

Comment: You can also have a repo factory which will create a repository by a database name for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems here:

1. You want a different implementation of your DB service at runtime.
2. The way you are switching on this is dependant on Http request parameters.

Ideally you want to abstract both of these away so your controllers don't have to worry about it at all, while still providing a good testable implementation.

I would suggest that you need a factory class to abstract away the logic of choosing a service, e.g.

```
public class DatabaseServiceFactory : IDbServiceFactory {

   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor  _contextAccessor;

   ctor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
      _contextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
   }

   IDataBaseService GetService() {

      var whichDb = //Get your parameter from the contextAccessor

      switch (whichDb) {
        ... return appropriate Db service in here with the correct repo type.
      }
  } 
}
```

This factory class then uses the IHttpContextAccessor to get hold of the request parameters.  This is both easily testable and removes the need to get this parameter within your controller - it is decoupled from how the factory decides on which DB service it needs.

And your controller then gets this factory injected:

```
public class AController : Controller
{
    prviate IDbServiceFactory _dbServiceFactory;

    public LoadDatabaseControllerBase(IDbServiceFactory dbServiceFactory)
    {
        DbServiceFactory = dbServiceFactory;
    }

    public ActionResult AnAction() {
        var dbService = _dbServiceFactory.GetService();
        ....
    }

}
```

I would also suggest that you don't have this in a base controller (probably adds very little).

Ideally, you wouldn't have this in a controller at all, but your logic abstracted out to a business/service layer, and it would be those classes that get the Db factory injected into them.

e.g.

```
FooService : IFooService {
   ctor(DbServiceFactory) {
   }
}

FooController : Controller {
   ctor(IFooService) {
   }

   ActionResult Index() {
       return View(_fooService.GetData())
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Init` method is trying to reinvent the constructor, but without the benefit of the language supporting it.

> 1. You need to KNOW to call Init() on the database. If you forget, you will get a lot of errors without a clear indication of where they are coming from.

This is precisely what the language provides for constructors. Constructors are a bottleneck where you can *force* the caller to pass by.

> Would you create a transient settings class which you populate in the controller and inject into the DatabaseService and Repository?

This is one of those functional *but dirty* implementations that is better avoided. This gets really dirty really quickly. To keep things clean, the DI container should be locked down by the time your controller logic executes, so you shouldn't try to still add something to the registration at that point.

However, you could implement a little helper that access the http context and parses out the name, and register that little helper. This is a viable approach. However, this only works on the web-project level, not below; which is why I opted for a different solution further down in the answer, one which can be applied on all levels.

> Is there a way to delay/pass the database name directly to DI so it can instantiate with the correct database name?

The above point of your DI container being locked in by the time you could supply the database name remains valid here.

Your approach is partly right, in that you need to go around DI to pass this custom argument. However, the `Init()` method is not the way to do it, because of the issues you've encountered yourself.

> 2. The repository called within the DatabaseService is not injectable since I need to pass it the database name. If I want to make it injectable I will again need to add an Init() or property that I have to set before using the repository, which in turn will result in the same issue as above

You're trying to fix the `Init()` problem by repeating the `Init()` problem a layer down, effectively passing the buck to the next layer. You've already shifted this once before from `DatabaseService` down to `Repository`.

There are two ways in which you tend to use a constructor:

- To inject dependencies (= predefined at the start of runtime)
- To pass specific arguments (= provided by your logic/user *during* the runtime)

The automation of the DI container makes it hard to pass arbitrary values at the same time. I believe this is what led you to develop `Init()`, to act as the second "constructor", the one which received the specifically chosen argument instead of the dependencies.

A better solution here is the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). This allows you to create a bottleneck that your code *must* pass by, which is effectively the solution to forcing how `Init()` *has* to be called.

With the factory pattern, you no longer inject your `DatabaseService`, but instead you inject a `DatabaseServiceFactory`, and it will generate the right `DatabaseService` for you.

Because you were also talking about an `Init()` for `Repository`, I infer that you're struggling with the same issue there. The same solution applies: `RepositoryFactory`.

The following is a small overview of the structure. I've omitted a few bells and whistles such as interface implementation for the sake of keeping the example simple and readable. Feel free to add these things back in.

The `RepositoryFactory` gets all the dependencies injected that the `Repository` should get, and stores them internally. I've used `IRepositoryDependency` as an example here.
Then, your code will call a specific `CreateRepository(...)` method on the factory, which provides the necessary argument, in this case the database name.

```
public class RepositoryFactory
{
    private readonly IRepositoryDependency _repositoryDependency;

    public RepositoryFactory(IRepositoryDependency repositoryDependency)
    {
        _repositoryDependency = repositoryDependency;
    }

    public Repository CreateRepository(string databaseName)
    {
        return new Repository(
                        _repositoryDependency, 
                        databaseName
                   );
    }
}
```

Notice how the factory pattern allows us to elegantly merge the injected repository dependencies with the custom arguments.

I leave the implementation of the `Repository` constructor up to you. Also, you will have to register `RepositoryFactory` in your DI container, and *remove* the `Repository` registration.

Now, the same pattern applies for `DatabaseServiceFactory`, with the added detail that it also has a dependency on the `RepositoryFactory`.

```
public class DatabaseServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IDatabaseServiceDependency _databaseServiceDependency;
    private readonly RepositoryFactory _repositoryFactory;

    public DatabaseServiceFactory(IDatabaseServiceDependency databaseServiceDependency, RepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
    {
        _databaseServiceDependency = databaseServiceDependency;
        _repositoryFactory = repositoryFactory;
    }

    public DatabaseService CreateDatabaseService(string databaseName)
    {
        return new DatabaseService(
                        _databaseServiceDependency,
                        _repositoryFactory.CreateRepository(databaseName)
                   );
    }
}
```

Note that I am again using `IDatabaseServiceDependency` as an example of any additional dependencies your database wants injected.

I again leave the implementation of the `DatabaseService` constructor up to you. All needed information is supplied there now. Also, you will have to register `DatabaseServiceFactory` in your DI container, and *remove* the `DatabaseService` registration.

And now, you can implement your controller:

```
public class LoadDatabaseControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected DatabaseServiceFactory _databaseServiceFactory;

    public LoadDatabaseControllerBase(DatabaseServiceFactory databaseServiceFactory)
    {
        _databaseServiceFactory = databaseServiceFactory;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

        var databaseName = Request.Host.Host.Split('.').First();

        var databaseService = _databaseServiceFactory.CreateDatabaseService(databaseName);

        // Now you can use your databaseService
    }
}
```

By hiding your `DatabaseService` type so that it can only be accessed through the `DatabaseServiceFactory`, you effectively *force* your code to pass by the `DatabaseServiceFactory` (and thus be forced to supply the database name). It cannot be forgotten, as you simply cannot meaningfully write any `DatabaseService`-handling logic without first getting the `DatabaseService` from its factory.

And even if someone ignores the factory and tries to instantiate a `DatabaseService` directly, its constructor forces them to supply all of the dependencies **and** the custom argument (such as database name), which again means that you cannot use a `DatabaseService` object without having supplied a database name.